# Input text in one column (a) if the value in another column (b) is found in another column (c)

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I have two lists of people - they will not be sorted in the same order. The second list is in a different sheet. If the person listed in column A shows up in Column A in the second sheet, I want column F to display "Y."  If not, I want column F to display "N."

This formula: `=ArrayFormula(vlookup(A2:A,Attendees!A2:A,1,0))` almost gets me there, but I can't figure out how to get it to return Y/N instead of the name of the Attendee or not.

Any ideas?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, Attendees!A2:A, 1, 0))="", "No", "Yes"))
```